# Generating a random point within certain distance from others

Tags: random, distribution, point

Coordinate system is 2D. X,Y values are double and can be negative too. And we have a little long point list.

Our new point must be further than 5000 from any point and must be closer than 20000 from at least one point. Also we should avoid imbalance distribution (growing in one direction). And if we have holes in distrubution we should to fill it.

1. Performance is important.
2. We do not need full accuracy for imbalance distribution or filling holes (as much as we can). But distance must be true (Between 5000-20000).

Current point list in database so we can order or pre-store any generated value.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: It sounds like your points form a fully connected graph, where the points are the nodes and the distances are the weights on the edges.  Perhaps googling some graph-theoretical methods may help?  Alternatively, optimizations or linear algebra methods might also assist.

Comment: How large is the dataset?

Comment: bigger then 200.000 points. Current points are not connected